# How to terminate sqlcmd immediately after execution completed?

Tags: c#, batch-file, sqlcmd

I create a process in C# to execute `sqlcmd /S <servername> /d <dbname> /E /i` to run sql script that create tables, views, stored procedures.

The problem is the process does not terminate after the execution is completed. I want to know how can I terminate sqlcmd immediately after the operation is completed.

Is there any input argument to sqlcmd that I can specify to terminate the process right away or can I do it directly in C#?

**Update**

This is the C# code that I use to execute the process.

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    ////var begin = DateTime.Now;
    ////context.TrackBuildWarning(string.Format("Start exec sql file at {0}.", DateTime.Now));

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlcmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-S {0} -d {1} -i \"{2}\" -U {3} -P {4}", sqlServerName, databaseName, file, sqlUserName, sqlPassword);
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit(); // if I comment out this code it will execute much faster

    ////context.TrackBuildWarning(string.Format("Finished exec sql file at {0} total time {1} milliseconds.", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.Subtract(begin).TotalMilliseconds));
}
```

As you can see, I have comment that if I remove (or comment) out `process.WaitForExit()` it will execute A LOT faster.

Comment: The solution would be to find out why it isn't closing after its finished?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I tried to run `sqlcmd /S ...` directly and it does terminate after its operation completed. I just updated my question to include my C# code, maybe there is something wrong in the code.

Comment: How much faster is "A LOT faster"?

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice 3.2 minutes vs 32.5 minutes. It does not make any sense for me, but it does faster.

Comment: Does your input file contain a large number of batches? For example, is it a script that creates hundreds of stored procedures in your database? In past experience, osql was terribly slow in that regard, taking upwards of 45 minutes to run such a script. I have not experienced that with sqlcmd, though. Also, just for the sake of comparison, when you execute this command directly at a command prompt, how long does it take?

Comment: I loop through all files in the folder and execute them one by one. This means that I create one thing (table, view, or procedure) at a time. I tried to run the command directly on cmd and it take less than 1 second. It has similar result if I comment out that line but it is really slow if I leave it there.

Answer (score 59):

Just use -Q (uppercase).

This command selects 'asd' and quits immediately:
`sqlcmd -S (local) -Q "select('asd')"`

Comment: sqlcmd.exe's -i argument executes SQL from a file which is what the OP wanted.  Your suggestion of -q or -Q are not the same- those arguments tell sqlcmd to take the query from the command line.

Comment: True, you got me. But -i argument always quits after executing the files.

Answer (score 3):

Simple use this syntax:

sqlcmd -q "exit(command)"

Comment: Just use -Q (uppercase). You do not need the exit(command) stuff

Comment: sqlcmd.exe's -i argument executes SQL from a file which is what the OP wanted.  Your suggestion of -q or -Q are not the same- those arguments tell sqlcmd to take the query from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have quit or exit at the end of your SQL file?

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the sqlcmd commands.

Comment: How can I know that the command is executed before the process is terminated if I specify `quit` or `exit` to the argument list? Is it 100% that the command is always executed before it quit?

Comment: sqlcmd will run all the commands in the file and put their output to stdout.  Your c# is capturing stdout and stderr.  You will have to read them once the process finishes and determine the results of your queries from that.